# calling other variables in a variable name (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, variable-substitution

At the moment I have the next paths

```
langs="EN GE"
dir_EN=/xx
dir_GE=/zz
```

As you can see the variable $langs has all possible languages in a single array. I would like to save all those paths in a multilingual (dir_ML) array using a loop which checks what the languages are, and then save the corresponding path. Here is what I have so far

```
for i in $(seq 0 1); do #I used seq because I didn't know how to specify the length of the variable $langs
    dir_ML[$i]=dir_${langs[$i]}
done
```

The output I am looking for is

`dir_ML[0]=/xx`

`dir_ML[1]=/zz`

I hope you can understand what I am trying to do!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`langs` is not an array but a string in your code.

To make it an array and use it:

```
langs=( EN GE )
dir_EN=/xx
dir_GE=/zz

dir_ml=()
for i in "${langs[@]}"; do
    declare -n p="dir_$i"
    dir_ml+=( "$p" )
done

printf 'dir_ml = "%s"\n' "${dir_ml[@]}"
```

In the above loop, `$i` will take the values `EN` and `GE` in turn. This also introduces a *name reference* variable `p`.  When the value of `p` is accessed, the string that was assigned to the variable when it was declared will be interpreted as a variable name and *that* variable's value is returned.

The output of the above will be

```
dir_ml = "/xx"
dir_ml = "/zz"
```

To use name references in `bash`, you will need `bash` version 4.3 or later.

---

Another (interesting but inferior) possibility:

```
dir_EN=/xx
dir_GE=/zz

# (can't set dir_ml=() here as its name would be picked up by the loop)
unset dir_ml

for i in "${!dir_@}"; do
    dir_ml+=( "${!i}" )
done

printf 'dir_ml = "%s"\n' "${dir_ml[@]}"
```

Here, `$i` will take the values of the *variable names* `dir_EN` and `dir_GE` in turn.  We then use *variable indirection* with `${!i}` to get the value of that variable. This variation does not need the `langs` array, but it instead assumes that *no other variable is named `dir_`-something* (which may be considered a bit fragile as a user may easily inject variables with names like these into the script's environment).

The output is the same for this code as for the code above.

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
langs=(EN GE)
dir_EN=/xx
dir_GE=/zz

for i in ${!langs[@]}; do
        temp="dir_${langs[i]}"
        dir_ML[i]=${!temp}
done
```

First I have changed `langs="EN GE"` to `langs=(EN GE)` because this needs to be an array.

I have also changed `$(seq 0 1)` to `${!langs[@]}` which will expand to the index (or name in the case of an associative array) of each item in the array.  So in this example `0 1`.

Then I set a temp variable to `dir_${langs[i]}` (`dir_EN` and `dir_GE`).

Then using the `!` parameter expansion I expand the variable with that name to set the element of `dir_ML`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You know? I still have a question. Could you explain to me why you used ${!langs[@]} instead of ${langs[@]} (without the question mark) I got confused with that

Comment: And also, I would like ask you why in the second line of the loop it is not necessary to use "$" before the i. Shouldn't it be used since it is a variable?

Comment: @little_mice `${!langs[@]}` generates the indexes of the array, `0` and `1`.  The `$` is not necessary in arithmetic contexts.